# To whom are Azure DevOps access request e-mails sent? And can that be controlled?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to control the recipients of the e-mail that's sent when a user requests access to a project in my organization in Azure DevOps? To what recipients/group is it sent by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to control the recipients of the e-mail that's sent
>   when a user requests access to a project in my organization in Azure
>   DevOps? To what recipients/group is it sent by default?

1.When requesting access to **organization level**, the email will be sent to **Project Collection Administrators Group** in Organization Settings.

[image]

2.When requesting access to one project with **project level**, the email will be sent to **Project Collection Administrators Group** in Organization Settings **and** Project Admins of that specific project.

[image]

[image]

Since you're requesting access to one project, admins of Organization(Project Collection Administrators) and that project(Project Administrators) will all receive the emails.

Apart from `Project Collection Administrators` group in Org settings, you also need to configure the `Project Administrators` group in Project Settings=>Permissions.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to match the behavior I'm seeing when people request access on a per-project basis.

Comment: Found this question because I wanted to know why some access requests went to Org Admins, and some went to Org Admins + Project Admins. But when I tested it myself based on this answer, requesting access to a specific project still only emails Org Admins.

Answer (score 1):

Project Collections Administrators group receives the email by default if a user requests access to a project.

So that means whoever is in the Project Administrators Group will receive the Email Notification and if you are the Owner of the Project/Organization, you can control the group by Adding/Removing the users.

Please see the below screenshot:

[image: Group1]

[image: Group2]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and screenshot. Are there any other users/groups that are notified when a user requests access to a project? Per your response, I looked at the list of "Project Collection Administrators" for my ADO organization and I compared it with the recipients of the access request e-mails and I see that the e-mails are definitely being sent to more users than just those in the Project Collection Administrators group (or any group nested in it)

Comment: @AuthInfant, I hope lance-Li's response helped solve your issue.